# iOS - how to move between view controllers without a button press

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm struggling to change to a UI View Controller as a game over screen, on this screen I plan on showing the score, reset and advert.  I'll show you my code that I have already then below I'll list how my project is set up.

The game runs however once contact is detected the crash states

`Thread 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)`

Here is the code I've used so far...

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var viewController: GameViewController!
var secondViewController: GameOverViewController!


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

//lots of code here

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if( moving.speed > 0 ) {
        moving.speed = 0;

self.viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("GameOverViewController", sender: self)

}
```

I currently have the below set up:

- My two view controller files `GameViewController.swift` & `GameOverViewController.swift`
- In addition to my current GameViewController view I have a new view controller on my storyboard with the following attributes.... `Class:GameOverViewController` & `Storyboard ID:GameOVerViewController`
- A triggered segue is set up (push) from `GameViewController` to `GameOverViewController`
- A then have the following code in my GameScene.Swift file

If anyone could help me that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried 'performSegueWithIdentifier("secondViewController", sender: nil)' not too sure if I'm missing something but its throwing up an error.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information, as well as a direct quote of the error message you are getting.  I would also suggest including more context than your little sample there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`performSegue:withIdentifier:` should work unless you have not setup the the storyboard correctly.

What error do you get on doing `performSegue:withIdentifier:` ?

Did you setup a segue in storyboard connecting the two view controllers and does that segue have an identifier called `secondViewcontroller`?

Take a look at this [Storyboard tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1).

Comment: Hello, I've edited the post to include more info, the crash error I get is `Thread 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)`

Comment: Replace the perform segue line with the lines below... `var vc:UIViewController! = self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController!
vc.performSegueWithIdentifier("GameOver", sender: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to push a view controller without a navigation stack, if that's your case, try presenting modally your view controller, check as well how do you have wired the segue. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Change your performSegue call to

```
 self.viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("DOES_NOT_EXIST", sender: self)
```

And re-test. Do you get the same error? If so, you haven't named your segue properly. The segue name set in the Interface Builder must exactly match the segue name you try to call in your code. To fix this: Select the segue in the interface builder, Read the Identifier box to the correct name, update your performSegue call to use exactly that string and rebuild. (if you update the identifier in the Interface builder, make sure you clean the project before rebuilding to ensure the new symbol is picked up).

If, however, the test results in a different error, "'Receiver <> has no segue with identifier 'DOES_NOT_EXIST'" then your original perform segue call was working fine. Put it back the way it was. Something else is causing your crash.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've checked the Segue identifier and  all seems to match up.  I'm really stuck on this one, would you be able to view my project on GitHub?  Here is a link [https://github.com/rich84ts/Ginger-Cat/blob/master/Ginger%20Cat/GameScene.swift#L312](https://github.com/rich84ts/Ginger-Cat/blob/master/Ginger%20Cat/GameScene.swift#L312) The link outlines the line where the code exists.

Comment: What happened when you tried the experiment I described? Did you receive the same error? Or the "no segue identifier" error?

Comment: It's a strange one, on the simulator I receive the same error but when i use my phone a different error is displayed on a file I've never seen before (0 function signature specialisation) `Thread 1: EXC_Breakpoint (code =1, subcode=0x10072d474`  any ideas?